# How to remove padding in Label control?

Tags: .net, winforms

How can totally remove padding in Label control?

I tried to set Margin and Padding properties to zero, but still I have few pixels of margin inside Label.

I want zero or very small (less than half of "space" character width) left and right padding in Windows Forms.

I need this for label placed very close to other, but when I place labels very close - background of label placed on top covers other label text. I use right align on one label, left on other label and it looks like this:

[image: padding]

I have this problem regardless of AutoSize property. There is always too much padding on right side of control.

In WPF it works as I want, but I have to use Windows Forms.

I can't use TextBox control (where it works as I want), because it does not support transparent background.

Comment: Margin and Padding have nothing to do with it, that's TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding, enabled for a Label control. It prevents certain glyphs, particularly italic ones, from falling outside of the bounding box. A simple but crude way to get rid of it is by setting the label's UseCompatibleTextRendering property to True.  Getting labels to overlap is just a case of not setting the Location property correctly.

Comment: Label does not contain property `TextFormatFlags`. Im looking in wrong place?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to look at the source code for the Label control.

Comment: You probably dont understand me. I have problem with background overlapping, because I have to place labels that way (wrong way), because I want narrow space between characters in 2 adjacent labels.

Comment: So how can I change TextFormatFlags?

Answer (score 4):

Try to set UseCompatibleTextRendering property to **true**.

Comment: This solved it for me! I had unwanted padding/margin inside the label. Now it's gone.

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining why this is the case (I'd certainly like to know).

Comment: What if my object is of a custom type of Control? Control doesn't have this property.

Answer (score 1):

You can totally remove padding if you draw the text yourself. Here is a simple custom label control (RightAlignment property changes text alignment)

```
public partial class NoPaddingLabel : Label
{
    private TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.SingleLine | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding;

    public bool RightAlignment
    {
        get
        {
            return (flags & TextFormatFlags.Right) == TextFormatFlags.Right;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                flags = flags |= TextFormatFlags.Right;
            }
            else
            {
                flags = flags &= ~TextFormatFlags.Right;
            }
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public NoPaddingLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, ClientRectangle, this.ForeColor, Color.Transparent, flags);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I used a Canvas layout to solve this:

```
<Canvas>
   <Label Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="0" Content="Latitude:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="red"/>
   <Label Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="0" Content="nn.nnnnnn" Foreground="red" />
   <Label Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="12"  Content="Longitude:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="red"/>
   <Label Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="12"  Content="nn.nnnnnn" Foreground="red" />
   <Label Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="26"  Content="Date" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Blue"/>
   <Label Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="26"  Content="Time" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Blue"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Question tagged winforms, not wpf